# MySQL (PHPMyAdmin) Find and replace

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

**I am a real newbie here so I 'think' this is really basic but...**

I have a table with 5 columns **id**, **code**, **date**, **class** and **classname**

I need to find cells in column '**class**' that equal '**295**' AND where cells in column '**classname**' are '**empty/blank**'

On the results of this search I need replace the empty cells in column '**classname**' with 'Text Value X'

Is there an SQL query that will do this? Or what is the best thing to do?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Look up the Update SQL query https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: `SELECT class, 'Text Value X' as classname 
FROM your_table_name
WHERE class = '295' AND (classname = '' OR classname is NULL);`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into [UPDATE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) statements and [WHERE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) clauses.

You are basically wanting something like this:

```
UPDATE your_table SET classname='X' WHERE class = '295' and (classname = '' OR classname IS NULL);
```

Try running a SELECT before running the above query just to be sure it will update the correct rows:

```
select * from YOUR_TABLE  WHERE class = '295' and (classname = '' OR classname IS NULL);
```

Comment: Thank you so much James for such a swift response.This worked a treat.  Best regards.